# How to create a native windows menu / ribbon for a DirectX 11 app

Tags: directx11, user-experience, interface, menu

I need to create menu items on top of my DX11 windowed app - similar to most windowed applications (File, Edit, etc...). How can I achieve this ? There is a `hMenu` handle to pass to the [DirectX window creation function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but I have no idea how to create this object.

Additionnaly I'd like to have 1 or several ribbons under the window menu with icons to trigger functionnality.

**EDIT** My menu is all good now and I chose to implement a [windows ribbon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316924%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but I'm still having problems at creating the ribbon. Here is a screenshot of my app. The green color is the Direct3D clear color - I would like my ribbon to display under the menu (and eventually remove the menu after that).

[image]

My ribbon code being :

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT paintStruct;
    HDC hDC;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        if (!SetupMenus(hwnd)) MessageBox(nullptr, TEXT("Failed to setup GUI."), TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);
    }

    // ...
}

bool SetupMenus(HWND hwnd) {

    // Create the menu
    // ...

    // Create the ribbon
    IUIFramework* pFramework = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = ::CoCreateInstance(CLSID_UIRibbonFramework, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pFramework));
    if (FAILED(hr)) std::cerr << "Fail #1" << std::endl;

    hr = pFramework->Initialize(hwnd, IUIApp);
    if (FAILED(hr)) std::cerr << "Fail #2" << std::endl;
}
```

outputs `Fail #1`. Why can't I create the ribbon ?

Comment: I would create A DX11 subwindow inside your standard window

Comment: Can you provide a link to how to achieve this ? I never used subwindows before.

Comment: technically all controls in Windows are windows so I just mean to say create a new window inside the current one, and use its HWND for your DirectX device -- this may require certain flags on the window to draw correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `CoCreateInstance` to work you need to prepare the call with either `CoInitialize` or `CoInitializeEx` function.

### [CoInitialize function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Initializes the COM library on the current thread and identifies the
>   concurrency model as single-thread apartment (STA).

### [CoInitializeEx function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695279(v=vs.85).aspx)

> Initializes the COM library for use by the calling thread, sets the
>   thread's concurrency model, and creates a new apartment for the thread
>   if one is required.

Answer (score 2):

There is a CreateMenu method you can use. More information on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646977.aspx

I don't know about the ribbon functionality.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316910(v=vs.85).aspx